# How to get rid of duplicates?

Tags: bash, grep, duplicates

Hi I am writing a script in bash which read the contents of files that have the word "contact"(in the current directory) in them and sorts all the data in those files in alphabetical order
and writes them to a file called "out.txt". I was wondering if there was any way in which I could get rid of duplicate content. Any help would be appreciated

The code I have written so far.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $(ls | grep contact) > out.txt
sort out.txt -o out.txt
```

Comment: "How to get rid of duplicates? [duplicate]" :D ..that made my day. Answer: you search for an existing question before you post your question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort` has option `-u` (long option: `--unique`) to output only unique lines:

```
sort -u out.txt -o out.txt
```

**EDIT:** (Thanks to *tripleee*)

Your script, at present, contains problems of [parsing ls output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs),

This is a better substitute for what you are trying to do:

```
sort -u *contact* >out.txt
```

Comment: Or better yet `sort -u *contact* >out.txt` to get rid of the unsightly [parsing of `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use this using the `uniq` command (easier to remember than flags)

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $(ls | grep contact) | sort | uniq > out.txt
```

or the `-u` flag for `sort` like this

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $(ls | grep contact) | sort -u > out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`uniq` may do what you need. It copies lines from input to output, omitting a line if it was the line it just output.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the "uniq" command, and pipe it through there after sorting.